# TQRChart for QR506 and Delphi XE6

Tags: delphi, teechart, delphi-xe6

Looking for a download link and instructions for adding the TQRChart QR506 component for Delphi XE6. I've found download links for CBuilder XE6 but none for Delphi. Any assistance would be appreciated. This is on Windows 7 64bit environment.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a Quick Report component suite which you can find and download from their official web site here: http://www.quickreport.co.uk/

BTW Quick Report component suite is also available for Delphi XE6 from 19.08.2014 which is just ten days ago. So don't scream at me that you already looked there but haven't found it. It is there now.

EDIT: My mistake. I thought that TQRChart component is a part of Quick Report component suite bit it seems that it is a part of Tee Chart component suite. So quick search on Tee Chart's website revelaed nex Guide of how to install TQRChart component into Delphi. Suposgnly it is even posible of adding TQRChart component without owning the Tee Chart component suite.

You can find guide about this here: http://www.teechart.net/reference/index.php

Comment: Hi - thanks. I just downloaded the lasted QR506 for XE6 from qusoft. After installing - the new one is the same as the one i had previously installed. I have the professional version and the version info is QR 5.06 Win64 Build 4 (02/06/2014). I see the note you mentioned about an update in the news section but the download is the same as the old version. And i remember getting the TQRCHart from the folks at Teechart in the past to recompile QRTee and add the TQRCHart to the QR component panel. But i haven't used Delphi since D7 - so i presume i am missing a step or something.

Comment: I have updated my answer with some aditional finromation which should help you out.